# How to write a program to add char []arr using stream in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class AddCharArray{
    public static void main(String [] as) {

        char [] arr = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            sum += arr[i];
        }
   }

}
```

> expected result should be : 294

Comment: If this was intended as a self-answered question, your question should be complete and on topic, and your answer should be more than just a dump of code. Your Q&A isn't very useful in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

```
char [] ch =  {'a','b', 'c'};

Integer sum = IntStream.range(0, ch.length)
              .mapToObj(i -> ch[i]).mapToInt(i-> i).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Integer sum = IntStream.range(0, ch.length).map(i -> ch[i]).sum();
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to map to the array value

Comment: i understand that you want the sum of the asccii values of each char

Comment: char Stream is not there so need to tack help of IntStream map  array elements with Stream<Character> type and then map to asccii values.

Comment: a char is a int, sum it like an int

Comment: and the result is 294

Comment: Yes it will interview question asked to me and i got answer myself and sharing it to help.

Comment: You're most likely going to see some down-votes here due to the vagueness of the question. You should also add more to the question, such as what you've tried so far. That we can help you in a more targeted way.